# How do I programatically put telerik rad grid in "add new" mode on page load

Tags: asp.net, telerik, radgrid

Seems like this should be easy but I must just be missing something...   I have a Telerik RadGrid on a page that allows inline editing.  How do I programatically put the grid into edit mode to insert a new row into the grid.   When the page loads I would like show the existing data and also display 1 empty row that a user can easily type into to add a new record to the table.   (I don't want them to have to push the add new button)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Found the answer while back....  updating this in case others need it

```
RadGrid1.MasterTableView.IsItemInserted = true;
RadGrid1.Rebind();
```

Answer (score 4):

Lifesaver!!

You can set

```
radGrid1.MasterTableView.IsItemInserted = false;
radGrid1.Rebind();
```

that will remove the inserted item (like pressing cancel).

Answer (score 3):

If you need show inset form always you can use next:

```
protected void NeedDataSource(object sender, GridNeedDataSourceEventArgs e) {
  parametersGrid.DataSource = data;
  parametersGrid.MasterTableView.IsItemInserted = true;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You could try using jQuery to press your add button once the page is ready.

Something along the lines of -

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#addButton").click();
}
```

Answer (score -1):

What I did when I wanted to do the same with the Telerik grid is to set the MasterTableView.IsItemInserted property of the control to true inside the OnNeedDataSource event handler. I suppose that it should work if you set the property inside the OnDataBound grid handler as well.

Dick

Answer (score -1):

```
RefreshGrid(userName, "priority", true, false);
RadGrid radGrid = RadGrid1;
radGrid.MasterTableView.InsertItem(); 
radGrid.Rebind();
```