# How do I open a Telerik RadGrid in "Add New" mode with default values pre-filled?

Tags: c#, asp.net, telerik, radgrid

From a hyperlink I need default values to appear when a RadGrid PopUp opens in "Add New" mode. It works fine when a RadButton is clicked (`CommandName="InitInsert"`). For that I set defaults in the `RadGrid_ItemCommand`:

```
if (e.CommandName == RadGrid.InitInsertCommandName)
{
    e.Canceled = true; 
    Hashtable values = GetDefaultValues();
    e.Item.OwnerTableView.InsertItem(values); 
}
```

The RadGrid's `MasterTableView` has `EditMode="PopUp"`. To cause the PopUp to appear from a link I've passed the text "AddNew" in the `queryString`. Then in `PageLoad` I set `RadGrid.MasterTableView.IsItemInserted = true;` [as described here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1792491/how-do-i-programatically-put-telerik-rad-grid-in-add-new-mode-on-page-load). What I can't figure out is **how do I get default values to appear in the PopUp that is triggered from a hyperlink?** A code sample would be much appreciated.

Comment: Have you tried binding the controls in the EditItemTemplate?
Text='<%# Bind("column") %>'

Comment: I was planning to use code behind. The default values will be user name, date added, customer code etc. I don't know if I can do that with binding but I'll look into it.

Comment: If you want to do it in code behind, do it in the itemdatabound event and then check if the grid is in edit mode. Then set the value of the controls in the template from the code behind by reference the row you have selected.

Comment: Sounds promising. Can you post an answer with a code sample?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
protected void RadGrid1_ItemDataBound(object sender, Telerik.Web.UI.GridItemEventArgs e)
{
    if(e.Item is GridEditableItem && e.Item.IsInEditMode)
    {
        if(e.Item is GridEditFormItem)
        {
            GridEditFormItem item = (GridEditFormItem)e.Item;
            TextBox TextBox1 = (TextBox)item.FindControl("TextBox1");
            TextBox1.Text = item["column"].Text;
        }
    }
}
```